# Login Error Joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla-2.5, router

There is some issue on my site when users visit directly http://spcrepsite.com (without www.) it works accurately, But when http://www.spcrepsite.com (include www.) it will show (homepage) that page without login which is not correct.

If the user did not log in it should show a login page.

If anyone directly opens http://www.spcrepsite.com it shows the following message but show all the content

Please login first

Comment: Hi Adeel. I don't see the problem you are saying. I can see the exact same page with the login form in both cases. Can you clarify what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to JSE Adeel, please take our [tour] and respond to FFrewin's request by [edit]ing your question.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered something similar in firefox where the cache was different for each domain name. Perhaps if you clear your browser caches for both sites www and non-www it will appear correctly for you.